# Map field name and value of model to table row instead of column

Tags: playframework-2.0

I want to create a model for application settings that can be changed by the application administrator.

The model should be stored in the database using ebean mappings:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

@Entity
public class ApplicationSettings extends Model {
    public String applicationTitle;
    public String companyName;
}
```

However, as there is only a single instance of ApplicationSettings, I want to store the settings in the database with a 2-columned table. The created table should look something like this:

```
create table application_settings (
  setting_name          varchar(255),
  setting_value         varchar(255)
);
```

The object's value of the *setting_name* column should then be named to the field names in *ApplicationSettings*, and the field value should be taken from the *setting_value* column.

Is there an easy way to achieve this with the play framework?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an built-in mechanism that supports that out of the box.

The easiest way to accomplish what you are asking for seems to do the following:

```
Map<String, ApplicationSettings> map = Ebean.createQuery(ApplicationSettings.class).findMap("settingKey", String.class)
String value = map.get("myKey").settingValue
```

for this to work your data model should look like this

```
@Entity
public class ApplicationSettings extends Model {
    public String settingKey;
    public String settingValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the suggested solution is exactly what i wanted to avoid. I wanted to be able to use the setting names by name in the scala templates (e.g. `@ApplicationSettings.applicationTitle`) with a row-based entity mapping. I guess I'll stick to the default column-based mapping until for now.